# referencing google play service for map R.java file error

Tags: android, google-play-services

i am trying mapv2 in my old application, which i published last year, now i am trying to integrate mapv2

i following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#overview)

work done till now:

- Install the Google Play services SDK.
- Add Google Play services as an Android library project.
- Reference the Google Play services in your app's project.
- this lib project works good with other projects,
- changed manifest

  ```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```

but the error comes while referencing google play service to my old project , it destroys all my resource file.

what could be the reason for this?

my project lib folder contains only updated support v4, i removed that as well but no use

i have googled it but didn't get any solution,
  so please help me,
 any suggestion are appreciated

thank you

Comment: **it destroys all my resource file** -- What does it mean?

Comment: Sorry for framing it wrong,it actually destroys my R.java file

Comment: Did you clean your project. Try to close the project and open it again.Also what is the error is being displayed in eclipse error log.

Comment: yes i already done that, & error log doesnt displays anything, in my source folder all class file which contains refrence to r file gives error

Comment: Eclipse has a view called problem view where you can see what is the original error in your project. Please take a look at the image for reference. http://smugappventures.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/aapt.png

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable About_us.java  line 74 Java Problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45167/discussion-between-tanmay-mandal-and-pitu)

Comment: what is your android api level set to ?? make sure it points to google_api

Comment: There are good answers here.  The mapv2 is a bear to get running.  I'd try practicing on the map examples first.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [`this`](http://swapnilsonarsblog.blogspot.in/2013/11/creating-google-map-application-using.html) link for Google Map v2 integration. This gives the step by step direction for map integration.

Hope this is helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have any error in your `res` folder. If you dont have any error mark (like this [image]) in your project explorer, probably you can do a further check:

1. Go to Console tab,
2. in the icon that looks like a screen make sure that Android is selected.
3. clear all the messages in the first icon, that is like a paper with a "X"
4. Go to Project > uncheck "build automatically"
5. Go to Project > clean

   - Select your procheck
   - Uncheck "start build inmediatelly"
   - click ok
6. In the project explorer, right click on your project name and click on *refresh*
7. Project > Build Project
8. Go back to the Console tab, and check if there are some errors, maybe regarding file names, or maybe file contents, usually in some of the folders inside the res folder

[image]

**Also**, please note that **you could be breaking your R file**, if some of the files in any of the resource files (an image, an xml file) or some of the value names (a string name, a integer name) has a duplicate name.  **Probably some of your files or values has a name that is also used in other resources, probably in the gooogle play services resources**. check for that.

Comment: console doesnt give any error,the image  which you had posted ,i even searched the id name in both the project, if they are conflicting ,but i ddnt got any similar words/ids :(

Answer (score 0):

The same situation I have crossed over a month back. Three things we need to check.

1. Check your `project.properties` file `target=android-17` and your Targetted Android version should be same.
2. Else check your Google Play services library project get connected properly in `project.properties` file like `android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib`
3. The final thing is like a magic trick, if the above steps are you tried already. Simply create another workspace and import your integrated code in it, and just link the play service lib project. Note: when importing your project, it will not give Android package also. In that time `Don't clean and build` and `do restart you Eclipse` like `File->Restart` in Eclipse.